# How to remote debug Linux binary from Mac OS X with IDA?

Tags: ida, debugging

I heard that you can run linux_server on the linux server you wish to debug remotely, but I only see references to Windows on the IDA site. Can we use OS X to remote debug a linux program with IDA? If so, how?

Comment: You are running the native IDA version for OSX? Or the Windows version in WINE?

Comment: I'm running the native version.

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of client build for remote debugging shouldn't matter. Just run the remote server and configure your client to connect to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have OS X? If so, could you provide the basic steps?